# Add params to after_sign_in_path_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to add parameters in the path returned in my `after_sign_in_path_for` function.
When a user is not authenticated and submits a form, i store the params and my website redirects him to the sign in form.

```
def create
    if current_user.nil?
      session[:form_data] = params
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path    
    else
      # here I handle form params
    end
end
```

Then the user logs in and here is my `after_sign_in_path_for` function.

```
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        if session[:form_data].present?
            '/transactions#create'
        else
            session[:previous_url] || root_path
        end
   end
```

If `session[:form_data]` exists, i would like to redirect him to transactions#create, but with `session[:form_data]` contents as parameters.

I tried to use `redirect_to` but it throws an exception since the devise function calling `after_sign_in_path_for` also calls `redirect_to`.

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The question here is if you should - redirects are `GET` requests. Your create action should only respond to a `POST` request since a `GET` request is stored in the browser history and may be inadvertently repeated.

What you could do instead is redirect to `transactions#new` and use the params to pre-fill the form:

```
def new
  @transaction = Transaction.new(new_transaction_params)
end

def new_transaction_params
  params.fetch(:transaction, {})
        .permit(:a, :b, :c)
end
```

---

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if session[:form_data].present?
    new_transaction_path(query: session[:form_data])
  else
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end
end
```

But if you have saved the form data in the session anyways there is no need to pass it via the params. In fact sending parameters in the query string is somewhat less secure.

This assumes that you have setup the routes with:

```
resources :transactions
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to find a way to submit that information without returning to that form. I think erasing session[:form_data] after using it would prevent users from sending inadvertently the data.